# Yodlee Site cannot be refresh

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to test the MFA in Yodlee with the dummy account DagBankTokenFMPA. I let the MFA timed out and now everytime, I try to refresh I got the same error :

```
{"siteRefreshStatus":{"siteRefreshStatusId":10,"siteRefreshStatus":"SITE_CANNOT_BE_REFRESHED"},"siteRefreshMode":{"refreshModeId":1,"refreshMode":"MFA"},"updateInitTime":0,"nextUpdate":2047149073,"code":522,"suggestedFlowReason":{"suggestedFlowReasonId":2,"suggestedFlowReason":"ACCOUNT_IN_ERROR"},"suggestedFlow":{"suggestedFlowId":3,"suggestedFlow":"EDIT"},"itemRefreshInfo":[{"memItemId":10088102,"itemSuggestedFlow":{"suggestedFlowId":3,"suggestedFlow":"EDIT"},"itemSuggestedFlowReason":{"suggestedFlowReasonId":2,"suggestedFlowReason":"ACCOUNT_IN_ERROR"},"errorCode":522,"retryCount":1}],"noOfRetry":1,"isMFAInputRequired":true}
```

How can I prevent that ? Do I need to stop the refresh with [stopRefresh](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/stopRefresh) and start over ?

Comment: I am encountering the exact same error! Did you figure out?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to call [updateSiteAccountCredentials](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/updateSiteAccountCredentials) API and just pass the details again, this will trigger a refresh and then you need to call getMFAResponseForSite to see what MFA information is required by the bank.

To add more, it seems like you are mixing two sets of APIs here. We recommend to either use container based APIs or Site Based set of APIs, in conjunction with Core APIs which are common to both.

Comment: We are using Site-based Services API.

Comment: So If I understand well, every time there is an error during the MFA during the refresh we need to call updateSiteAccountCredentials ?  Is there a way to just call getMFAResponseForSite to get a new MFA token/captcha without asking the user to reconnect to his bank with his login/password ?

Comment: Hi @Roma, did you get a solution for the situation you have mentioned in a comment. Even I am trying to add same functionality in my application. But could not do it properly. It will be helpful if you give me some thought on it.

Comment: @bunty Resuming the presence over the portal after long time, as Yodlee fetch this information in real time, it is required to initiate a refresh process. Hence, you need to call that API or you can speak to Yodlee support team to allow you to call [startSiteRefresh](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/startSiteRefresh) , where you don't need to ask user's credentials and only have to get MFA info required by bank at that time.